こよ at the end of a sentence
Context: I'm reading a manga, and there is a scene where a class of high schoolers are talking to their class pet, who can also talk as well. One girl asks "Why doesn't the class pet just run away from school?" To which the pet responds "I'm too scared that I'll get killed by a stray cat.". One of the male students then say:

じゃ今度教室に猫連れてこよ

I know that the bulk of what he is saying is "Then next time, I'll bring a cat to class", but what does the こよ at the end of the sentence mean?

This is just a clipped form of 連れて来よう "let's bring".
